# multiply set of columns by one column in data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I know that I can use mutate across to multiply one columns by other specific columns like this:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(across(disp),.*carb)
```

In my data, both my variables are numeric:

```
> str(trad_clean_weighted$Q10_1)
 num [1:1024] NA NA 0 1 NA 0 0 NA 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "label")= chr "Q10_1.Dance assessed and reported via report card"
> str(trad_clean_weighted$wgt_part1B)
 num [1:1024] 9.73 1.9 3.09 3.1 21.42 ...
```

However, I get this error when I try to multiply the columns:

```
my_data %>%
mutate(across(Q10_1),.*wgt_part1B)

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `..2` is `. * wgt_part1B`.
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error when both variables are numeric! :(

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `across` got closed after the column name.

```
my_data %>%
        mutate(across(Q10_1, ~ . * wgt_part1B))
```

If there are vector of column names, specify those within the `across`

```
nm1 <- c('Q10_1', 'Q10_2')
my_data %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(nm1), ~ .* wgt_part1B))
```

FOr a single column, we don't need to use `across`

```
 my_data %>%
      mutate(Q10_1 = Q10_1 * wgt_part1B)
```

Comment: I am actually multiplying a vector containing several columsn... sorry for the poor example, I'll fix my post to reflect that.